# Custom border of view

Tags: swift, uiview, border

Good day the community, I have to set the buttons to change the views with custom border, when I click on it, the second view is closed and the view with this border is displayed.
[image]

Help me please ;) Thx

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far. Don't expect us to write the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

`UIView` has layer property which is in charge of "borders" and inherits from `CALayer`. All you need to do - write custom CALayer class, customize it in craziest way you can  and then override layer class in your UIView like so:

```
override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        get {
            return YourCustomdLayer.self
        }
    }
```

Hope it will help you. Good day!